# Bring logo and slider on the same line.(Unslider.js)

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, unslider

I am trying to bring logo and a slider (unslider.js) on the same line but for some reason bootstrap column doesn't work.

Here is the code I am trying:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- Slider -->
  <script src="//unslider.com/unslider.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <img src="./img/merchant-logo.png" class="img-responsive" style="height: 50px; width:auto;">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="banner">
          <ul>
          <li><img src="img/merchant-logo.png"  /></li>
          <li><img src="img/merchant-logo.png"  /></li>
          <li><img src="img/merchant-logo.png" /></li>
          <li></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
        $('.banner').unslider();
        });
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

right now it is coming something like this

[image]

Comment: i think you forget to specify  **float:left** to logo img ....
try adding it ... it will work

Comment: I mean for the whole time I was doing float:right for slider and finally this float:left worked..thanks